# Control an LED through internet

Tags: android, wifi, html

I am creating an Android app to control a LED through internet.
First I built an application using app inventor and it's working fine
as shown in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-2CyGM9QNs&list=LLOG_1YPENk_YX8ypNpRgPuA&index=2

[image]

Now I am trying to build the same application using Android Studio and I am facing some problem, not getting the exact output as I got from app inventor

Here is code for the button:

```
 public void ON(View view)
 {
     Intent led_on = new 
     Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("192.168.43.104/LED=ON"));
     startActivity(led_on);
 }
```

Created a button which should turn ON the led, but it's going to the webpage
How to do it without going to webpage as done in app inventor?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to start an activity when clicking on the button, but doing a [GET request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) instead.

**UPDATE:**

It seems you don't care about the response of your request, so you can simply do something like:

```
 public void ON(View view) {
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("192.168.43.104/LED=ON"));
 }
```

Make sure to have INTERNET permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanks
But its showing
""Cannot resolve symbol HttpClient"

Comment: You have to add it in the dependencies on your build.gradle file: `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'` and then import it.